# How to stop UITableView scrolling to top after insert new row?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, tableview, catransition

I have used accordian view in my app, While I insert new row in the `UITableView`, everything works good if the section is in visible area. But when we update lower section row, `UITableView` scrolls to top automatically. Whats the issue here? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
   [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
     NSLog(@"Completed");
    } 
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [CATransaction commit];
```

Any suggestion? I tried `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, `setContentOffSet`.

Comment: You can set the tableview bounces property to NO.

Comment: Thanks, yes i did but no solve.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using autolayout to let the tableview calculate the cell height? If yes, you have to set the `estimatedHeight` closed to the actual height of cell asap. If you have different height for different cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt
indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

"accordian tutorial" works because it uses fixed cell height.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but here's a list of things you can try :

- Setting `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO` before your update and `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES` right after
- Not sure but you can try to set `self.tableView.scrollsToTop = NO`
- Save current position of scrollView in a `CGPoint`, then right after your update call `[self.tableView setContentOffset:previousPosition animated:NO]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you put the lines ? `[self.tableView setContentOffset:previousPosition animated:NO]` should absolutely work if you put it after `[CATransaction commit]`

Comment: I put it in completion block and it works. But I used  
'withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic' , so it looks wierd animation.

Comment: yes it works. But doesn't look like accordian animation.

Comment: Will it be sufficient for you or do we have to search further ?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, Yes am searching for other solution. Hope i ll find it.

Comment: And if you have some good accordian tutorial links or library please share here.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about accordian tutorials. Hope you've find yourself ! :)

Comment: Ok Thanks once again :)

Comment: This https://github.com/kuon/ios-example-accordion is good one. Do check.

Comment: Thanks once again :)

Comment: You can check the answer as correct as storing `CGPoint` and restore with `setContentOffset` will work for most of users :)